# How to use static expressions in a Automapper Profile?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

We have static classes to centralize our expressions

```
public static Expression<Func<PersonEntity, bool>> IsActivated()
    => pe => pe.ActivatedOn != null;
```

So we can just write  e.g.

```
  DbContext.Persons
  .AsQueryable()
  .Where(PersonsQuery.IsActivated())
  .SingleOrDefault();
```

instead of

```
  .Where(pe => pe.ActivatedOn != null)
```

Which works in all kind of providers we use (e.g. Entity Framework).

But in Automapper this does not work in a Profile.

```
.ForMember(p => p.ActivatedPersons,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.Persons
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(PersonsQuery.IsActivated())
            .SingleOrDefault()))
```

This results in

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression1' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

If we use

```
.ForMember(p => p.ActivatedPersons,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.Persons
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(pe => pe.ActivatedOn != null)
            .SingleOrDefault()))
```

it works.

Is there a way we can use our static expressions?

Exception Stack Details:

> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionExtensions.UnwrapLambdaFromQuote(Expression
> expression)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor) System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> node)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor) System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> node)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor) System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> node)F
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression
> node)
> System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor) System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> node)
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment
> node)
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding
> node)
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection
> nodes, Func<T, T> elementVisitor)
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression
> node)
> System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor) System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> node)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor+PendingSelectorExpandingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> expression)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression
> query)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression
> query)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression
> query)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor(Expression
> query)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery(Expression
> query, bool async)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore(IDatabase
> database, Expression query, IModel model, bool async)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0()
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery(object
> cacheKey, Func<Func<QueryContext, TResult>> compiler)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync(Expression
> query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync(Expression
> expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable
> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Can you show call stack?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv sorry, added.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is known EF limitation. You can solve that only by third party extensions.

https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler

https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq

Simple sample using `DelegateDecompiler`

```cs
[Computed]
public static bool IsActivated(PersonEntity pe)
    => pe.ActivatedOn != null;
```

Automapper

```cs
.ForMember(p => p.ActivatedPersons,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.Persons
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(pe => PersonsQuery.IsActivated(pe))
            .SingleOrDefault()))
```

Final query

```cs
DbContext.Persons
   .AsQueryable()
   .Where(pe => PersonsQuery.IsActivated(pe))
   .Decompile()
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

It is important to call `Decompile` or `DecompileAsync`

P.S.

I like how it was done by `DelegateDecompiler`, but `nein-linq` also usable. Also `LINQKit` can help here with its `Invoke`. But everything needs additional call `Decompile()` or `ToInjectable()` or `AsExpandable()` according to library.

Comment: Mh... its weird because it works in EF but not if I use this in the AutoMapper Profile. LINQKit has too much side-effects. So thanks for all your hints I'll check what we do..

Comment: @BenjaminAbt, in Automapper variant you defines Expression.  So `PersonsQuery.IsActivated()` is become MethodCallExpression but for parsing that EF expects LambdaExpression.  For getting Lambda from MethodCall it should Invoke method -  but it doesn't.

Comment: Libraries that I have mentioned preprocess ExpressionTree and make EF happy.

Comment: We had so many troubles with the generated code with LINQKit.. :-/

Comment: LINQKit, is simple library for correcting Expression Tree. Problems in usage is leak of knowledge how LINQ works.